# Finding the derivative of $\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

1. Use first principles to find the derivative of the following.
   $$\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

[image: Thats what i have done so far]

Comment: Differential Equations?

Answer (score 2):

I assume first principles means $\frac{d}{dx} f(x) =\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac1h (f(x+h)-f(x))$. Then
\begin{align}
(f(x+h)-f(x)) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+h)^2-1}} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}-\sqrt{(x+h)^2-1}}{\sqrt{(x+h)^2-1}\sqrt{x^2-1}} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}-\sqrt{(x+h)^2-1}}{\sqrt{(x+h)^2-1}\sqrt{x^2-1}} \cdot 
\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}+\sqrt{(x+h)^2-1}}{\sqrt{x^2-1}+\sqrt{(x+h)^2-1}} \\
&=\frac{\left(\sqrt{x^2-1}-\sqrt{(x+h)^2-1}\right)
\cdot\left(\sqrt{x^2-1}+\sqrt{(x+h)^2-1}\right)}{\sqrt{(x+h)^2-1}\sqrt{x^2-1}\cdot \left(\sqrt{x^2-1}+\sqrt{(x+h)^2-1}\right)}
\\ &=
\frac{\left({x^2-1}-{(x+h)^2+1}\right)
}{\sqrt{(x+h)^2-1}\sqrt{x^2-1}\cdot \left(\sqrt{x^2-1}+\sqrt{(x+h)^2-1}\right)}
\\ &=
\frac{-\left(2xh+h^2\right)
}{\sqrt{(x+h)^2-1}\sqrt{x^2-1}\cdot \left(\sqrt{x^2-1}+\sqrt{(x+h)^2-1}\right)}
\end{align} 
Now if we consider $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac1h (f(x+h)-f(x))$ we can see, that the enumerator is $-2x$ while the denominator becomes $\sqrt{x^2-1}\sqrt{x^2-1}\cdot \left(\sqrt{x^2-1}+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)=2\sqrt{x^2-1}^3$.

Thus
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{x^2-1}^3} = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}^3}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

You should evaluate 
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{((x+h)^2-1)^{-1/2}-(x^2-1)^{-1/2}}{h}.$$ in your calculation, you have $(x+h-1)^{-1/2}$ in place of $((x+h)^2-1)^{-1/2}.$

Answer (score 1):

Ill provide an answer using the limit definition of a derivative, which may or may not be easier to follow

$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{((x+h)^2-1)^{-1/2}-(x^2-1)^{-1/2}}{h}
$$

$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{[((x+h)^2-1)^{-1/2}-(x^2-1)^{-1/2}]\times[((x+h)^2-1)^{-1/2}+(x^2-1)^{-1/2}]}{h[((x+h)^2-1)^{-1/2}+(x^2-1)^{-1/2}]}
$$

$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{((x+h)^2-1)^{-1}-(x^2-1)^{-1}}{h[((x+h)^2-1)^{-1/2}+(x^2-1)^{-1/2}]}
$$
since

$$
\frac{1}{(x+h)^2-1} - \frac{1}{x^2-1} = \frac{h(-h-2x)}{(x^2-1)(h+x-1)(h+x+1)}
$$

$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{-h-2x}{(x^2-1)(h+x+1)(h+x-1)[((x+h)^2-1)^{-1/2}+(x^2-1)^{-1/2}]}
$$

$$
=\frac{-2x}{2(x^2-1)(x^2-1)\sqrt{x^2-1}}
$$

$$
= \frac{-x}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}
$$